# Size of parentheses around \vec in contrast to \tilde with mathpazo

Tags: mathpazo, parentheses

The `mathpazo` package reduces the size of automatically sized parentheses around accents like `\tilde` and `\hat`. However, it does not do it for `\vec`.

This minimal example shows this very well:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
$\left(X\right)$
$\left(\hat{X}\right)$
$\left(\tilde{X}\right)$
$\left(\vec{X}\right)$
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to also reduce the size of parentheses around `\vec`?

Edit: I am writing a document of about 200 pages with many complicated formulas using nested parentheses. In addition, I use named variables instead of the symbols themselves. This means that the symbol of a variable can change afterwards. Therefore, I really need a solution that automatically adjusts the size of the parentheses instead of me going through every formula and adjusting the sizes by hand. I want to adjust the `\vec` command so that it acts like `\hat` and `\tilde` in terms of its height.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is there a reason for using `\left` and `\right` in all of these cases, even though they're absolutely not needed?

Comment: `$\bigl(\vec{X}\bigr)$`

Comment: This is a clear demonstration that one should *not* use `\left` and `\right` except when they're useful and this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the size of parens you are seeking is `\big`.  But as Mico asks, if you want a particular size, should you even be using `\left(...\right)`, as these will autoscale (and maybe not in the desired way).

As has been pointed out elsewhere, using `\big` family of size adjusters has the added advantage over the `\left(...\right)` syntax in that it can be broken across multi-line math expressions.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
$\left(X\right)$
$\left(\hat{X}\right)$
$\left(\tilde{X}\right)$
$\bigl(\vec{X}\bigr)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you accept the wisdom of this approach, a better way to have achieved the result would be with

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
$(X)$
$\bigl(\hat{X}\bigr)$
$\bigl(\tilde{X}\bigr)$
$\bigl(\vec{X}\bigr)$
\end{document}
```

Mico goes a step further in his comment below, and suggests there is no need to resize parens just for diacritical marks.

**FOLLOW UP**

The OP pleads for an alternate approach that auto-adjusts paren height.  I don't recommend this as a general fix, and can't guarantee that it works in all cases (the 1.51 pt was empirically determined; 1.50 shrinks the `\vec X` paren and 1.53 grows the `\vec\beta` paren).  But this may get the OP through his/her current bind.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\let\svvec\vec
\def\vec#1{\ensurestackMath{\vphantom{\addstackgap[1.51pt]{#1}}}\smash{\svvec{#1}}}
\begin{document}
$\left(X\right)$
$\left(\hat{X}\right)$
$\left(\tilde{X}\right)$
$\left(\vec{X}\right)$

$\left(\alpha\right)$
$\left(\hat{\alpha}\right)$
$\left(\tilde{\alpha}\right)$
$\left(\vec{\alpha}\right)$

$\left(\beta\right)$
$\left(\hat{\beta}\right)$
$\left(\tilde{\beta}\right)$
$\left(\vec{\beta}\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, this is the default behavior of `mathpazo`:

[image]

Comment: +1 for trying to encourage the OP not to use autosized large parentheses. My earlier comment actually aimed to go even farther: I can see no valid (typographic) reason for enlarging the parentheses just so that they enclose the diacritics above the letter `X`. IMNSHO, `$\bigl(\vec{X}\bigr)$` -- though certainly better than `$\left(\vec{X}\right)$`, is still inferior to `$(\vec{X})$` ...

Comment: @Mico  Thanks.  Certainly your point is something more for the OP to consider.

Comment: I really need an approach that automatically adjusts the sizes of the parentheses. Basically, I want `\vec` to behave exactly like `\hat` with regards to `\left(` and `\right)`. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @Kocki Please see update.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I have accepted it. Incidentally, I came up with a different solution right before you posted yours. I will post it as well for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution by Steven B. Segletes, I have found another one. I will post it here for the sake of completeness:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\let\oldvec\vec
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\smash{\oldvec{#1}}\protect\vphantom{\hat{#1}}}

\begin{document}
$\left(X\right)$
$\left(\hat{X}\right)$
$\left(\tilde{X}\right)$
$\left(\vec{X}\right)$
\end{document}
```

In the cases I have used `\vec`, this solution works well. However, I cannot guarantee that it will work in all cases as I am no TeX expert.